# Return values from a timed out sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, timeout

I need to return values ​​from a sql query that has a timeout:

IDbConnection connection ...; 
connection.Query  (query, whereConditions, null, true, 60);

after 60 seconds, the timeout occurs, but I need to return values ​​found in that time. Does anyone have an idea how can I do this?

Comment: You can't.  Is the query designed in such a way that all the rows need to be found before the first row is returned (because, say, you need to do an `ORDER BY` and the query plan isn't using an index to guarantee that the results are in a particular order without doing a separate sort)?  If you just do a straight `select * from table`, for example, executing the query should execute it only as far as it takes to return the first N rows (N being something the client configures).  Subsequent fetches will cause the query to be evaluated further.

Comment: You can't. Timeouts are a failsafe. I would suggest making several smaller queries (using ROWNUM and possibly Flashback queries) to make several smaller queries that each work fine, but only returns a partial result. Then, after 1 minute, stop.